# Allow C# generic type constraint to accept either single instance of object or IEnumerable

Tags: c#

Feeling like I might be out of luck with this one but thought I'd give it a try.

I have a class that accepts a generic constraint as follows:

```
public MyClass<T>
    where T : IMyInterface
{

    public MyClass(T payload)
    {
        Payload = payload;
    }

    public T Payload { get; }

}
```

This works just fine as long as I'm constructing with a single instance of IMyInterface. But what if I want T to be and IEnumerable of IMyInterface? This does not work.

I tried specifying multiple types in the constraint as follows...

```
public MyClass<T>
     where T : IMyInterface, IEnumerable<IMyInterface>
```

... but this does not appear to work as the compiler wants to satisfy both contraints instead of just one or the other. Also tried multiple constructors but this was also problematic.

Comment: Consider spliting `MyClass<T>` into `MyClass<T> where T : IMyInterface` and `MyClassCollection<T> where T : IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`.

Comment: A complete answer will depend on the purpose of the T parameter and IMyInterface constraint. In the code you've provided, nothing accesses members of T or IMyInterface, and therefore you don't need a generic parameter at all. Instead, you could change the type of Payload to `object`, and introduce two constructors, one that accepts IMyInterface and one that accepts `IEnumerable<IMyInterface>`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu - great point. This class is intended to be the serializable response from an API controller, which will then be deserialized by the consuming service. So, 1) I want to preserve strong typing across the application layers, and 2) while object is convenient, it is potentially insecure.